# Sabre SOAP call returning empty string

Tags: java, web-services, soap, sabre

Have a Java Web service that was working previously and all of a sudden last week broke.

The version of the request has not been updated in forever, it is on version 1.2.7 and the current version is 1.7.5, so I'm not sure if that is the issue.  I've debugged through the code, and the HTTP headers, the createSessionRQ, and everything else works fine, but Bargain Finder Max calls end up throwing a SAXException when being parsed, `java.io.IOException: '' For input string: ""`.  This happens as soon as I try to parse the incoming message, on the first pass.  All other responses are parsed fine.  And the parsing code is all from apache axis 1 library.  Example XML is below.  Again, this was working up until last week.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
     <SOAP-ENV:Header>
      <eb:MessageHeader SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1" eb:version="1.0">
       <eb:From>
        <eb:PartyId type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">company</eb:PartyId>
       </eb:From>
       <eb:To>
        <eb:PartyId type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">webservices.sabre.com</eb:PartyId>
       </eb:To>
       <eb:CPAId>0WPB</eb:CPAId>
       <eb:ConversationId>convoid</eb:ConversationId>
       <eb:Service eb:type="OTA">Air Shopping Service</eb:Service>
       <eb:Action>BargainFinderMaxRQ</eb:Action>
       <eb:MessageData>
        <eb:MessageId>mid:0_2014-09-22T21:43:40m</eb:MessageId>
        <eb:Timestamp>2014-09-22T21:43:40</eb:Timestamp>
        <eb:TimeToLive>2014-09-22T21:43:40</eb:TimeToLive>
       </eb:MessageData>
       <eb:DuplicateElimination/>
       <eb:Description>Bargain Finder Max Service</eb:Description>
      </eb:MessageHeader>
      <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" xmlns:wsu="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/utility">
       <wsse:BinarySecurityToken>tokenhere</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
      </wsse:Security>
     </SOAP-ENV:Header>
     <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns1:OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ Version="1.2.7" xmlns:ns1="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
          <ns1:POS>
          <ns1:Source PseudoCityCode="0WPB">
          <ns1:RequestorID ID="1" Type="1">
      <n

s1:CompanyName Code="TN">TN</ns1:CompanyName>

</ns1:RequestorID>

</ns1:Source>

</ns1:POS>

      <ns1:OriginDestinationInformation RPH="1">
  <ns1:DepartureDateTime>2014-10-31T00:00:00</ns1:DepartureDateTime>

  <ns1:OriginLocation LocationCode="BWI"/>

  <ns1:DestinationLocation LocationCode="MBJ"/>

      <ns1:TPA_Extensions>
  <ns1:SegmentType Code="O"/>

</ns1:TPA_Extensions>

</ns1:OriginDestinationInformation>

      <ns1:OriginDestinationInformation RPH="2">
  <ns1:DepartureDateTime>2014-11-03T00:00:00</ns1:DepartureDateTime>

  <ns1:OriginLocation LocationCode="MBJ"/>

  <ns1:DestinationLocation LocationCode="BWI"/>

      <ns1:TPA_Extensions>
  <ns1:SegmentType Code="O"/>

</ns1:TPA_Extensions>

</ns1:OriginDestinationInformation>

      <ns1:TravelPreferences>
  <ns1:CabinPref Cabin="Y" PreferLevel="Preferred"/>

      <ns1:TPA_Extensions>
  <ns1:TripType Value="Return"/>

</ns1:TPA_Extensions>

</ns1:TravelPreferences>

      <ns1:TravelerInfoSummary>
  <ns1:SeatsRequested>1</ns1:SeatsRequested>

  <ns1:AirTravelerAvail>
  <ns1:PassengerTypeQuantity Code="ADT" Quantity="2"/>



</ns1:AirTravelerAvail>

</ns1:TravelerInfoSummary>

      <ns1:TPA_Extensions>
      <ns1:IntelliSellTransaction>
  <ns1:RequestType Name="50ITINS"/>

</ns1:IntelliSellTransaction>

</ns1:TPA_Extensions>

</ns1:OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ>
 </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an Axis 1 issue, you can either upgrade to axis 2 or perform the below modification:

should be changed to:

CommonHTTPsender is an improved version of HTTPSender.

Hope this information is helpful.

Comment: That did it.  changing the client-configuration.wdll in the axis.jar to use transport method CommonsHTTPSender.  Also had to include the necessary jars to get it working with that.